# What does it mean for a sequence to be Cauchy in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

General speaking I understand when we say a  sequence $\{f_n\}$is Cauchy,
that is $\forall \epsilon >0$ , $\exists \mathbb{N}$ such that  given $n,m \geq \mathbb{N}$, $|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$.

But when we say $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^p$ for say $1\leq p<\infty$,
what does it mean? Does it mean $\forall \epsilon >0$ , $\exists \mathbb{N}$ such given $n,m \geq \mathbb{N}$,

$$\|f_n-f_m\|_{L^p} <\epsilon$$ or 
$$\|f_n-f_m\|<\epsilon$$

Comment: It is the first one.

Comment: The former.${}$

Comment: A sequence in a normed space $(X,\|~\dot~\|_X)$ is called Cauchy if the definition holds for the $\|~\cdot~\|_X$-norm. In your case, it is the $L^p$-norm $\|~\cdot~\|_{L^p}$.

Comment: $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy with respect to a metric $d(f,g)$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N$ such that $d(f_n,f_m) < \epsilon$ for all $n,m \ge N$. "Cauchy in $L^p$" means you apply the above definition with the metric $d(f,g) := \|f-g\|_{L^p}$.

Comment: What norm is used in the second case?

Comment: It is certainly the former. Whether or not it is also the latter, it depends entirely on what you expect $\lVert f\rVert$ to be for a function $f\in L^p$.

Comment: The first paragraph in the post is unclear. In what space are you talking about the sequence $\{f_n\}$ and what does $|\cdot|$ mean in $|f_n-f_m|$?

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful explanations. @Jack I am talking about the absolute value function in the first paragraph.

Comment: Then $\{f_n\}$ must be a sequence of real numbers or complex numbers. Otherwise, it does not make sense to say $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: What does $\|f_n-f_m\|$ mean in your question?

Comment: @Jack I was actually talking about real valued functions. Also by $||f_n-f_m||$  I mean $\int_X|f_n-f_m|$

Comment: If you are talking about real-velued functions in the **first** paragraph, then it is completely wrong: what does $|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$ mean when you claimed in a previous comment that $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value?

Comment: @Jack can you explain more why it is wrong?

Comment: The answer is in my question, what does $|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$ mean?

Comment: Consider for instance, $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. What do you mean by $|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the $L_{p}$ norm that is used here. To see why, just note that every norm $|| \cdot ||$ can induce a metric by $(x,y) \mapsto || x - y ||$.